# Can I store my users in array on PHP then access the full list in another page?

Tags: php

I have a question about php and how it works on server side.

Im thinking about creating array of users in PHP than access it. When user access the website, my script will push the username to array. Can I access this array in another page without using the database to store the usernames?

Comment: This is the purpose of an SQL (or similar) database, I don't know why you wouldn't want to use one. However, you could: serialise the array (and store it in a DB, or file), json_encode the array (and store in  a DB, or file).

Comment: you can access using session,store array of user in a Session and retrieved in other page

Comment: No, PHP will refresh the page and lose all variables per every page load. You will need to use a database like MySQL, or sessions as mentioned, but sessions are stored on the client's side, they expire and data can be lost.

Comment: you can, with PHP sessions! you can start reading this http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php .... anyway if the reason of this is check user password for example I highly recommend to store the data in a database

Comment: Yes , but Is it possible to do? I run on a server a script and let it running and I will be storing the data on the memory ram.

Comment: You can use cookie,session or global variables like wordpress does.

Comment: yes, with sessions as mentioned. Give that a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: Ok I have already use sessions and cookies to store information, but Im just thinking if I can do like I said. Do u guys know if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. This won't work as you described. You can either use a database (typical with PHP is MySQL but there are many other options) or a file (JSON or any of a number of other formats). But the key is understanding **why it won't work**:

I think you are looking at PHP on the server as **one** system serving **many** users. However, from the perspective of PHP, each user is seeing a fresh and separate instance of the PHP system. Depending on how the server is actually configured, there may or may not be multiple PHP processes running at the operating system level. But at the application level, each instance (run) of a PHP program is totally independent, with **its own copy of all local (RAM) data storage - including arrays.** That is NOT necessarily the case in all languages, but for practical purposes you can treat a PHP server process as if it were a separate server brought online to serve the one current user, then rebooted to serve the next user. With that setup, it should be clear that the only way for the server process serving the 2nd user to see what the 1st user did is if the process serving the 1st user stored the information in non-volatile storage - e.g., MySQL or a file on disk. The advantages of a database over a simple file are that it allows fast & easy queries of the information and hides most of the little details of cooperation between the different server processes - e.g., if there are 10 users all accessing the server at basically the same time, the individual PHP server processes don't have to worry about who can write the file "now".

In addition to the problem of each server process seeing (or not seeing) the data collected from other users, even within a single user the data is not available. Each PHP page request, including regular POST or GET and AJAX calls too, starts a fresh PHP instance (again, this is logically speaking - the server code may actually be resident and not reloaded, but it runs "fresh" each time), so with the exception of session data (as others have rightly suggested) there is no data carried over between pages even for an individual user. Session data is normally limited in size and often is just used as a reference into server-side data stored in files or a database.

Answer (score 0):

Without database- use sessions. Add session_start() on every page you want to access your users array, and then $_SESSION["session_variable_name"] = $users_array to assign your array to session variable. Then if you want to use it, just access it like a usual variable: echo $_SESSION["session_variable_name"][0].

But using database would be much more appropriate. Session variables are accessible only on that session, so if there's new user added to the array, only client who added it will see it. Each user will have his own session, where user array may be completely different from what others will see.

What I'd do- after successful login to the system, assign username to session variable, and then if I want to perform a task for that user, say, get his email address from database, I'd make sql query, selecting email from users, where username equals to username stored in session.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to prepare user details array as per below

```
$userDetailArr = array(
    'username' => 'foobar',
    'id' => 1,
    'email' => 'foobar@foo.com'
);
```

now add session_start(); function and store above array into $_SESSION variable

```
$_SESSION['userdetail'] = $userDetailArr;
```

$_SESSION['userdetail'] you can use anywhere you want. but make sure to add session_start() function at top of page before use session variable.